# How do you find the voltage in this three phase circuit?

Tags: voltage, three-phase

[image]

The picture shows a circuit of 3x380/220V and it is asked to solve for the indication of the voltmeters. I can´t get any hint on how to find the Vc voltage.
The box with the delta symbol indicates that there is a balanced load of Z in delta connection.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like you are missing a lot of context. Where did this schematic come from?

Comment: Also, what is a "balanced charge in Z"? What exactly is in the delta box?

Answer (score 1):

> *I can´t get any hint on how to find the Vc voltage.*

Redraw to enable you to focus on what value Vc is relative to GND/Earth: -

[image]

You can probably assume that each line to earth is 220 volts hence, the line voltages will be 380 volts. You can probably assume that the incoming supply is connected to earth at it's effective star-point and, that the voltages are balanced.

So, you just need to consider voltages X and Y and use an equal potential divider (formed by the two Z impedances) to calculate the voltage Vc.

You could even use a simulator to get the result you need.